# add row to datagridview while OleDbDataReader.read()

Tags: c#, oledbdatareader

I use C# and WindowsForms.

I want to insert a record to database and then add too my gridview

I test the codebellow but it dosent work.

```
 //some codes here
 OleDbDataReader dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
 while (dr.Read())
            {
            //DataGridViewRow row=new DataGridViewRow(); ????
            //Gview.Rows.AddNew(...) ???
            // what sould I write here??
            }
```

How can I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to get the values out of your DataReader, then you need to assign them as a row. The simplest way is to add them as an object array: I've added a using statement to make sure the reader is correctly disposed of after use.

```
// some codes here
using (OleDbDataReader dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
{ 
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        string f1 = dr.GetString("Field1");
        string f1 = dr.GetString("Field2");
        GView.Rows.Add(new object[] {f1, f2});
    }
}
```